# Configuring unit tests

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2012, ide, nunit

Recently made a switch from java netbeans where I used JUnit, to VS 2012 (c#). I'm new to this IDE and was hoping if anyone here could share a guide on how to configure Unit Testing. I understand NUnit is a popular option but can't seem to find info on how to setup on the IDE. 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you don't need to use NUnit as VS comes with MS Test, which needs no setup.  Just use the TEST menu option;  write your tests and TEST->Run.  the MS Test attribute syntax is a little different to Nunit.

But to use the NUnit UI you can create your NUnit project by opening your test dll (from your project\bin\debug directory) - and set the NUnit advanced options to reload the project when the dll changes.  That way each time you recompile your tests, NUnit picks up the change, and you can use the Nunit UI immediately.